# Generate URLs with parameters in Freemarker similar to jstl's c:url

Tags: jsp, jstl, freemarker

I am newbie to Freemarker & am pretty sure there would be an easy way to do this. Essentially in my jsp page I have something like this,

```
<c:url var="myURL" value="/amount">
    <c:param name="currency" value="dollars"/>
</c:url>
```

I am porting this to .ftl now. So I wanted to know is there a way to do it in ftl? I dont want to pass the url from the servlet. There are way too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a direct translation for that into FreeMarker, but you could write a [custom directive](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_misc_userdefdir.html) to handle that easily.  FreeMarker has built ins for [URL escaping](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_url) as well.

Comment: I did end up using URL escaping. Thanks!